# second row select tag is not rendering select tag in same row

Tags: jquery

i have added a row dynamically but my second row select tag change the first row select tag. any help would be appreciated.

code snippet

```
        function change(id) {
                var url = ServerURL + "/StockService.asmx/GetStoneName?id=" + id;
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

                    var $select = $('#ddlStoneName');
                    $select.find('option').remove();
                    for (var j in data) {
                        $select.append('<option value=' + data[j].Id + '>' + data[j].Name + '</option>');
                    }
                });
        }

        $(document).delegate("#ddlStoneType", "change", function () {
            change($("option:selected", this).val());
        });

$('#btnaddrow').click(function () {
                $('#gvStoneDetail tbody>tr:last').clone(false).insertAfter('#gvStoneDetail tbody>tr:last');         return false;
        });
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**

> The #id selector selects the element with the specific id. and it must be unqiue for every element.

Your main problem is here :

```
var $select = $('#ddlStoneName');
```

You have given the same `id` to your `second <select> tag` as well as first one, you help you to get this better , in javascript if you are using an `id` for an `element` it should be `unique id for unique element`

let's say i have 3 divs with same id :

```
<div id="mydiv">my div 1</div>
<div id="mydiv">my div 2</div>
<div id="mydiv">my div 3</div>
```

javascript will alert me "my div 1" if i will execute this kind of code (same as yours but basic way):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selector = jQuery('#mydiv').text();
  alert(selector);
});
```

in this case what the javascript will do is go through your html document and take the first tag with first similar selector it found and take it's values. you have to use different id's for every single element / identify them as siblings.

for your code you can do this to easily get into what you want to achieve , first change your id to a class then it will work as you want it to work  so `#ddlStoneType`  will become `.ddlStoneType`  and `#ddlStoneName` will become `.ddlStoneName` , and inside you `<select>` tags as well change them from : `id="ddlStoneType"  to class="ddlStoneType"` and so on:

```
    // removed your function {} and added its code inside the code below use the code below:


    $(document).delegate(".ddlStoneType", "change", function () {
        var id = $("option:selected", this).val();
        var $select = $(this).parent('.make').find('.ddlStoneName');
         var url = ServerURL + "/StockService.asmx/GetStoneName?id=" + id;
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $select.find('option').remove();
                for (var j in data) {
                    $select.append('<option value=' + data[j].Id + '>' + data[j].Name + '</option>');
                }
            });
    });
```

And here is basic example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vsmf22tp/

Comment: and how can i change select tag id of second row with above given code of add row

Comment: @Sippy  check my answer edit ,, i have removed your function change() and added it's code directly from where you did call it , use the code i have given in answer , it will be done

Comment: <tbody>
            <tr class="make">                
                <td style="width:10%;">
                      <select class="ddlStoneType">
      
                        <option>Stones</option>--%>
                    </select>
                

                </td>
                <td style="width:10%;">  
                    <select class="ddlStoneName">
                        <option>--Select--</option>
                       
                    </select></td> </tr>         this line is not working   $(this).parent().find('.ddlStoneName'); in this senerio

Comment: @Sippy check my edit and use that code it will work.